# Trying to declare a class, needs a "home" body?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a class with a list of numbered events and then will use that in another class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// a list of events indexed by number
class EventList{
  Map<int, String> event_list = {};

  EventList(){
    event_list[0] = "Hello!";
  }
}
```

However, when I try an use it in my main class, I get an error:

```
EventList eventList();
```

The error is:

```
error: 'eventList' must have a method body because '_homeState' isn't abstract. (concrete_class_with_abstract_member at [citadel_test] lib\pages\home.dart:12)
```

I realize I can't use an empty constructor, but even when I change it to use an optional color paramter, I get the same error.

Comment: The issue is with the way you are creating an instance of the EventList class. Try using the something like: `EventList eventList = new EventList();` or `EventList eventList = EventList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code like this

```
// a list of events indexed by number
class EventList {
  Map<int, String> event_list = {};

  EventList() {
    event_list = {0: "Hello!"};
  }
}
```

then use it like this

```
EventList eventList = EventList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EventList eventList();
```

This is **not** a constructor call. This is the declaration of a method called `eventList`, taking no parameters and returning an `EventList`. It is just the declaration, with no body (code in `{` and `}`). That is why you get the error, that you class cannot have a method with no body.

If you want a field of type `EventList` in your class, it needs to be:

```
EventList eventList = EventList();
```

This creates a field of type `EventList` and fills it with the result of the constructor call.